# Understanding Apostol's proof of the Lagrange remainder theorem

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

The proof is:

[image]

What I don't understand in this proof is (1): how does he manage to bring about a third subtraction term in the second last expression. I assume that he is expressing the function $h(t)$ in terms of the remainder $f(x)$ and the polynomial $p(t)$ for $h(t)$, which also doesn't make sense since we know that the remainder should then be $R(t)=f(t) - p(t)$. So basically, what does his second last expression represent and where is it derived from. And, my second questions is: how does he exactly "apply the lemma for a fixed x" to the second last expression to obtain Lagrange's formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author doesn't derive $h(t)$.  Instead he defines a function $h(t)$ as
$$h(t) = f(t) - p(t) - \left[\frac{f(x) - p(x)}{x^n}\right]t^n$$

He then applies the lemma to obtain the final expression.  I'll show the details.  We can take the $k$th derivative of both side to obtain:
$$h^{(k)}(t) = f^{(k)}(t) - p^{(k)}(t) - \left[\frac{f(x) - p(x)}{x^n}\right]\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}t^{n-k}$$
Evaluating at $t = 0$
$$h^{(k)}(0) = f^{(k)}(0) - p^{(k)}(0)$$
for all $k < n$.
Since $p$ is the $n-1$st Taylor polynomial, this is $0$ for all $k<n$.  Applying the theorem, we see there is a $t = \eta$ such that
$$0 = h^{(n)}(\eta) = f^{(n)}(\eta) - p^{(n)}(\eta) - \left[\frac{f(x) - p(x)}{x^n}\right]n!$$
Since $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, this reduces to:
$$0 = f^{(n)}(\eta) - \left[\frac{f(x) - p(x)}{x^n}\right]n!$$
Finally, rearrange terms to get the desired expression.

Comment: I understand that he didn't derive the formula for $h(t)$, but can you explain how it is valid?

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú Given any function $f$ I can define $p$ to be it's Taylor polynomial of degree $n-1$.  Then I can define a function $h$ to be their difference, or product, or whatever I like.  All such functions are "valid".

Comment: Sorry, another question. Why the kth derivative of h of zero equal to zero? I understand the kth derivative if the polynomial would be zero but how can we justify that the kth derivative of f of zero is also zero?

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú   The $k$th derivative of the polynomial is not zero at $t=0$.  It is equal to the $k$th derivative of $f$ at zero.  This is because it is the $n-1$th degree Taylor polynomial.

Comment: So is h of t zero for its kth derivative then?

Comment: Yes, because $f^{(k)}(0) - p^{(k)}(0) = f^{(k)}(0) - f^{(k)}(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer has gone straight into my "proof notes" (including Apostol's too).